# Python - Modifying a backreference. Can it be done?

Tags: python, regex, backreference

New to Python so please forgive my ignorance.  I'm trying to modify backreferenced strings in a regular expression.

Example:

```
>>>a_string
'fsa fad fdsa dsafasdf u.s.a. U.S.A. u.s.a fdas adfs.f fdsa f.afda'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\s)(([a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]\.{0,1})(?=\s)', '<acronym>'+re.sub(r'\.',r'',(r'\1').upper())+'</acronym>', a_string)
'fsa fad fdsa dsafasdf <acronym>u.s.a.</acronym> <acronym>U.S.A.</acronym> <acronym>u.s.a</acronym> fdas adfs.f fdsa f.afda'
```

Instead of the output I desire:

```
'fsa fad fdsa dsafasdf <acronym>USA</acronym> <acronym>USA</acronym> <acronym>USA</acronym> fdas adfs.f fdsa f.afda'
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

> If *repl* is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of *pattern*. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string. For example:

And see the example contained in the linked docs.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I don't know how this helps me.  The example doesn't use a backreference.  When I take the backreference out and, say insert a dummy string, it works fine.  The problem is in the modification of the backreferenced string (I think).

Comment: Did you try returning a replacement string?

Answer (score 3):

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams suggested, you can solve your problems by passing a callable function to `re.sub()`.  I figured that sample code would explain it best, so here you go:

```
import re

s = "fsa fad fdsa dsafasdf u.s.a. U.S.A. u.s.a fdas adfs.f fdsa f.afda"

s_pat = r'(?<=\s)(([a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]\.{0,1})(?=\s)'
pat = re.compile(s_pat)

def add_acronym_tag(match_object):
    s = match_object.group(0)
    s = s.replace('.', '').upper()
    return "<acronym>%s</acronym>" % s

s = re.sub(pat, add_acronym_tag, s)
print s
```

The above prints:

```
fsa fad fdsa dsafasdf <acronym>USA</acronym> <acronym>USA</acronym> <acronym>USA</acronym> fdas adfs.f fdsa f.afda
```

So you aren't actually modifying the backreference, because strings are immutable.  But this is just as good: you can write a function to do any processing you want, and then return whatever you want, and that is what `re.sub()` will insert in the final result.

Note that you can use regular expressions inside your function; I just used the `.replace()` string method because you just want to get rid of a single character, and you don't really need the full power of regular expressions for that.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.  But I'm still not sure why my initial attempt didn't work.  Don't re.sub() and upper() count as callable functions?

Comment: They count as callable functions.  But `re.sub()` calls the function and passes a single argument: a "match object".  `re.sub()` and `str.upper()` don't know what to do with a match object.  Look again at my function; the first thing it does is extract the string from the match object.  So, you need to write a wrapper function that calls `re.sub()` or `str.replace()` and `str.upper()`; the wrapper needs to take a match object as an argument; and the wrapper needs to not take any other arguments to tell it what to do.

Answer (score 2):

The "*modifying a backreference*" needs re-phrasing as you seem to confuse the notions.

A [*replacement backreference*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) is a special *combination of characters* iniside a *string* that tells the regex engine to refer to some specific capturing group values (aka *submatches*) retrieved during a match operation.

When you use `r'\1'.upper()`, you are trying to make the `\1` string uppercase, and as `\1` has no uppercasable letters, you get `\1` as a result, and this `\1` - unchanged - is applied as the (part of) string replacement pattern.

That is why you can't modify the capturing group value this way.

That is why you have to [use a callable as the replacement argument](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) (see [Ignacio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7279235/3832970)): you need to pass the match object to the `re.sub` to be able to manupilate the *submatches* (although you may of course replace a char or two in a backrefence, say, `r'\g<12>'.replace('2','1')` to "obfuscate" `\g<11>` backreference, but there is little sense in this operation).

Comment: Posted in an attempt to make it clearer as [more questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58023380) appear.

Answer (score 1):

### Context

- python 3.x
- using re.sub to do regular expression substitution
- apply arbitrary modification on part of a string, without modifying the whole string

### Problem scenario

- UserMattL/uu002matt1675257544 wants to match part of a string with regex
- user wants to modify the matched part of the string

### Solution

- The general solution to this scenario is already posted [elsewhere in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7279487/42223)
- This answer shows a simpler example that does basically the same thing, but using python `lambda` instead of declaring a standalone function

### Example

- user has a string matching a MSFT Windows filepath specification
- user wants to change the drive letter to lowercase, but without modifying any other part of the string
- regex is appropriate here, since the drive letter can be any character, making `str.replace()` impractical

```
  import re
  ss7676demotest = 'D:/AlphaOne/BravoTwo'
  rx7676demotest = re.compile(r'^(\w):')
  ss7676demotest = re.sub(rx7676demotest, lambda obmatch: '{vjj}:'.format(vjj=obmatch.group(1).lower()), ss7676demotest,)
  print(ss7676demotest) ## d:/AlphaOne/BravoTwo
```

### Rationale

- python `lambda` allows user to minimize the amount of code

### Pitfalls

- the question talks about modifying a backreference, but that's actually not what's going on here

  - backreference is a regex concept for specifying subregions of a string that match a specific part of a regex
  - in this context, we want to specify one of those matched subregions so we can modify it without affecting any other part of the string
  - we do that with python `regex.match()` object (eg, `obmatch.group(1)` in this example)
- python `lambda` is practical in simple scenarios that do not involve a lot of logic, but not always favorable

  - for more elaborate transformations, it is favorable to write a standalone function instead of using a lambda
  - to enhance readability
  - to make the code more maintainable
  - see the [other answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7279487/42223) for the alternate non-lambda approach